# Angular 2 to 6 Upgrade WrappedError Missing

Tags: angular, angular6, custom-error-handling

I am trying to upgrade a project from Angular 2 to Angular 6 and the `import { WrappedError } from '@angular/core/src/facade/errors';` is throwing the `Cannot find module...` error in my Custom Error Handler implementation. I use the `WrappedError` in the following contexts:

```
this.findContext((error as WrappedError).originalError);

let e = (error as WrappedError).originalError;
    while (e && (e as WrappedError).originalError) {
        e = (e as WrappedError).originalError;
    }

let e: any = error;
    let stack: string = e.stack;
    while (e instanceof Error && (e as WrappedError).originalError) {
        e = (e as WrappedError).originalError;
        if (e instanceof Error && e.stack) {
            stack = e.stack;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of where it has been moved to and how to include it or a work around?

Comment: The type file `node_modules/@angular/core/src/error_handler.d.ts` has information in the comments on how to replace the default implementation. The default implementation can be found at `node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/src/error_handler.js`

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade npm, node, and angular cli?  I'm pretty sure you will need to in order to go from 2 to 6.

Did you try look at this?
https://update.angular.io/